# RPC failed; Curl 56 OpenSSL error when deploying app to heroku

Tags: express, heroku

I keep getting the following error when i try to push my application using heroku.

```
numerating objects: 62, done.
Counting objects: 100% (62/62), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
Writing objects: 100% (62/62), 16.52 MiB | 25.21 MiB/s, done.
Total 62 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, 
errno 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

What I've tried:

1. Increasing postBuffer size

   `git config --global http.postBuffer 52428800000`
2. deleting/ reinitializing git init

somethings that may be relevant.
-The app size is about 140MB.

- I use express, multer, sessions

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and I used this command to fix the issue:
**git push heroku master --force**

Comment: I don't know if that will work but if i run into the issue again I will try. I fixed the issue by pushing my code through the heroku web browser